# Flex Catch Keydown

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to handle the keydown event globally in my application and as such have added the event handler to the top most DisplayObject in the display list. However, the event doesn't seem to fire unless the cursor focus is on a Textbox or Datagrid or the like.

How can I have key presses handled globaly by the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stage.addEventListener(...)` ?

Comment: You're right but I guess the question is WHEN to I create this event listener. Googling the issue recommends adding the event listener during FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE but that event never seems to fire

Answer (score 2):

In response the OP's comment above, here's how to hook it up correctly, namely in the application's `creationComplete` event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="initApp();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.managers.SystemManager;

            public function initApp():void {
                systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown)
            }

            public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
                pressedKey.text = event.charCode.toString();
            }           
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Label x="486" y="63" text="You pressed: "/>
    <mx:Label id="pressedKey" x="577" y="58" width="122" text=""/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you won't detect any keystroke until your flex application get the focus.
You can do it automatically by calling a js script at startup that will set the focus on the application

Once done, I would recommand you to add your key listener on systemManager. Doing that will allow you to handle keydown event globally.

Comment: Doesn't AC_FL_RunContent set focus automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
ExternalInterface.call('function browserFocus(){document.getElementById(\'APPLICATION_NAME_HERE\').focus();}');
```

This works only with IE and Opera.